# error creating blog subsite in code

Tags: 2010, feature-activation

Im creating a blog subsite in the featureactivated event but it errors out everytime i activate the feature.  looking at the logs i can see there is an access denied entry however the blog subsite is created fine.  Heres my code

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        LoggerWrapper lw = new LoggerWrapper();

        try
        {
            SPWeb thisWeb = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;

            using (SPWeb newBlog = thisWeb.Webs.Add(
                "TeamNews", 
                "Team News", 
                "News Blog", 
                1033, 
                "BLOG#0", 
                false, 
                false));

            lw.Information(
                "blog site provisioned for " + 
                ((SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent).Name, 
                Categories.Event.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = 
                "Error provisioning blog site for " + ((SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent).Name + "\n\n" +
                ex.Message;

            lw.Error(ex, message, Categories.Event.Unexpected);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine the error coming from one of the following:

- The LoggerWrapper - Does the current account have access to write to where it writes? (EventLog?)
- A feature stabled onto either BLOG#0 or GLOBAL#0